# Ida Plugin Batch analysis issue.

Tags: ida, ida-plugin, idapro-sdk

I overcame recent issues with a redefinition and finished my Plugin.

In short this plugin uses Hex-Rays Decompiler to decompile a given file, analyzes properties of the pseudocode and then appends the results to a `.csv`

Now I tried to use this in batch mode, but was stumped as the following happened:

Cmd input to call IDA:

```
idaw -A -c -Srecompile.idc input_file
```

The `recompile.idc` file:

```
#include <idc.idc>
static main() {
Wait();
Message("Hello world from IDC!\n");
RunPlugin("REcompile vs Hexrays",0); 
//Exit(0);
}
```

I obviously need to `Wait()` for Auto-Analysis. `Exit()` is commented since it's for use when this is all fixed.

Now i do get the following output on execution:

```
The initial autoanalysis has been finished.
Hello world from IDC!

LoadLibrary(C:\Program Files (x86)\IDA\plugins\REcompile vs Hexrays.plw) error: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.
C:\Program Files (x86)\IDA\plugins\REcompile vs Hexrays.plw: can't load file
Hex-Rays Decompiler plugin has been loaded (v1.6.0.111005)
Hex-rays version 1.6.0.111005 has been detected, REcompile vs Hexrays ready to use
```

As you can see the script is executed before the plugins are loaded. I assume this is the reason why I get the `LoadLibrary` Error.

If you have any other input or experience with plugin batch execution i'd be happy to hear from you.

Greetings, 
Viktor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried manually loading the Hex-Rays plugin before loading your plugin?

For example:

```
#include <idc.idc>
static main() {
    Wait();
    Message("Hello world from IDC!\n");
    RunPlugin("hexrays",0);
    RunPlugin("REcompile vs Hexrays",0); 
    //Exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that solved it. I actually made a double mistake of using the wanted_name(), instead of the .plw-file name. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad it worked! Yeah, the documentation isn't very clear regarding the first argument for `RunPlugin()`.